# chef local kitchen apt-get update stuck

Tags: chef-infra, ubuntu-14.04, apt-get, test-kitchen

I am trying to configure Ubuntu 14.04 locally on Mac. I have:

```
apt_update "update apt sources" do
   action :update
end
```

in the receipt and overtime I run it using `kitchen converge`, the program stuck at the following:

```
* execute[apt-get -q update] action run
             - execute apt-get -q update
```

If I don't run this and directly login using `kitchen login` then run `sudo apt-get update` it finishes quickly. I don't what to do. Please help!!

UPDATE: if I wait, it can finish in about 10 minutes - I am not sure why it is so slow - used to be very fast.

Comment: Does your workstation have an HTTP proxy stuffs set?

Comment: I don't think so, see screenshot at https://www.dropbox.com/s/i6qd389gmpocb3u/Screenshot%202016-05-10%2016.11.42.png, apt-get update can finish but it takes a long time for no reason. Thanks for your help.